# How to save a folder instead of a file using jFilechooser?

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

So basically what i am stuck with is that I have this jFrame where i have two TextAreas and i want the save button to behave in such a way that when i enter save and navigate through the directories and enter some name and press save i want to save a folder which consists of these two files . Here is the code that i am using to save one of those textAreas and hence i have two save buttons to save both , Can someone suggest something so that when i enter save i have both these files inside that folder.

Here is the code i m using:

```
String content = Area.getText();

 JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();

 chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("/home"));

 int retrieval = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);

 if (retrieval == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

    try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(chooser.getSelectedFile()+".txt")) {
                fw.write(content.toString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced this problem before and I came up with this solution :

```
String content = Area.getText();

JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("/home"));

int retrieval = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
if (retrieval == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    try {
       File dir = new File(chooser.getSelectedFile().toString());
       dir.mkdir();
       System.out.println(chooser.getSelectedFile().toString());
       File file = new File(chooser.getSelectedFile().toString()+ "/temp.txt");

       if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
       }

       FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
       BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
       bw.write(content);
       bw.close();
   }
   catch (Exception ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

See what it does is it gets you the exact location of where you made the folder using `chooser.getSelectedFile()` and then using that you can add a file inside that.